# Unset array from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, session, multidimensional-array

Here are my functions. I have a problem with removing and editing shopping cart.

Earlier I had only two parameters in array $id and $quantity, but I had to add $varianta which stores for example size, etc.

Insert and foreach of $_SESSION['cart'] works like a charm, but as I said removing and updating not.

**function addToCart()**

```
    public static function addToCart($data) {

        $id = $data['id']; //id
        $quantity = $data['qty']; //qty
        $varianta = $data['varianty']; //varianta

        //ověříme, zda $_SESSION['cart'] 
        if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
            $_SESSION['cart'] = array(); 
        }

        array_push($_SESSION['cart'], array(
            'id' => $id,
            'quantity' => $quantity,
            'varianta' => $varianta
        )); 
    }
```

**function editCart()**

```
public static function editCart($data) {
    //edit quantity +-
}
```

**function removeFromCart()**

```
public static function removeFromCart($id) {
        unset($_SESSION['cart'][$id]); //DOESNT WORK
    }
```

I would be thankful if somebody told me how to approach what I am trying achieve.

Thank you.

Comment: As you are using array_push $_SESSION['cart'][$id] does not exist. What exist is something like $_SESSION['cart'][0][$id]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you have not set the `$id` as index in `$_SESSION['cart']` try this

```
  public static function addToCart($data) {

        $id = $data['id']; //id
        $quantity = $data['qty']; //qty
        $varianta = $data['varianty']; //varianta

        //overíme, zda $_SESSION['cart'] 
        if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
            $_SESSION['cart'] = array(); 
        }

        $_SESSION['cart'][$id] = array(
            'quantity' => $quantity,
            'varianta' => $varianta
        )); 

    }
```

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly, but how can I edit quantity?